# How to uninstall Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

Please tell me how to uninstall my laptop is falling apart. I tried using an iso but it wouldn't mount and using the boot menu at startup won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You should require to format your system by some other operating system.
such as Windows or any other Linux. That is the only way to remove any operating system